# How do I convert this decryption function from PHP to Objective C?

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption, base64, aes

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to decrypt data. I have a php version working and would like to port it to my iOS project.

This is the working php function:

```
public function decryptCBC($data, $key, $iv) {
        // Decode the key and IV.
        $iv = base64_decode($iv);
        $key = base64_decode($key);
        // Decrypt the data.
        $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
        return substr($data, 0, -$padding);
}
```

In Objective C, this is what I've tried but no success yet

```
- (NSData *) decryptCBC:(NSData*)data WithKey:(NSString *)key andIv:(NSString *)iv {

    NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
    NSData *ivData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:iv options:0];

    key = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:keyData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with 0s - padding

    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = data.length;

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0 ,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          [ivData bytes],
                                          [data bytes], dataLength,
                                          buffer, bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation

        NSData *response = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted-1];
        return response;
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate an answer.

Thanks
/Jonathan

Comment: Provide a hex dump of the key, iv and data in and out of both functions. There is some concern about the padding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **exactly** the same input and the inputs are **exactly** the right length you will get **exactly** the same result.

The one issue: the same padding must be used for each but you are not using padding in the decryption, you are doing something external for padding.